# Setting REMOTE_USER for Trac in Gunicorn behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, authentication, trac, gunicorn

I want to run Trac in Gunicorn, behind Nginx. Nginx handles user authentication via LDAP (which works), but I can't get the `REMOTE_USER` passed to Trac.

For uWSGI I would configure Nginx like this (tested and it works):

```
uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
```

For Gunicorn I could not find a similar configuration directive. I have tried setting the header, but it doesn't seem to change anything:

```
proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
```

There is [an entry in the Trac wiki about this](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/Gunicorn), noting that *"the wsgi entry point does not handle [...] authentication"*, and a workaround to handle Basic Authentication with a local password file, which is not what I need. Do I need to change my entry point to pass this `REMOTE_USER` header to the right environment variable? Currently it's just this:

```
import sys
import os

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

os.environ['TRAC_ENV'] = '/path/to/my/trac'

import trac.web.main
application = trac.web.main.dispatch_request
```

Answer (score 7):

Strange one. I got this working by including the this in the nginx config like you mentioned

```
proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
```

Then for the trac.wsgi file this

```
import trac.web.main
def application(environ, start_application):
    environ['REMOTE_USER'] = environ.get('HTTP_REMOTE_USER')
    return trac.web.main.dispatch_request(environ, start_application)
```

replaces this

```
import trac.web.main
application = trac.web.main.dispatch_request
```

in your trac.wsgi

Apparently there is something about the proceeding 'HTTP_' that messes up trac's auth

I am guessing that the same thing probably could be accomplished by doing the same thing to just the 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' request header but I didn't attempt that. So I do not know for sure, all I know is that it works now!

Comment: I can confirm this also works when using CherryPy / Cheroot as the WSGI server behind NGINX.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Mercurial; byoungb's answer, above, is OK in principle but should be using `X-Remote-User`, not `REMOTE_USER` in the `proxy_set_header`, and then `HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER` in the `environ.get()` call.

However, since most people use SSL and then do Basic authentication, you can use the `Authorization` header (which arrives in your environment as `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`) as follows:

```
import base64, re

def use_basic_auth(application):
    def auth_app(environ, start_response):
        auth = environ.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        if auth:
            scheme, creds = re.split(r'\s+', auth)
            if scheme.lower() != 'basic':
                raise ValueError('Unknown auth scheme \"%s\"' % scheme)
            user, pword = base64.b64decode(creds).split(':', 1)
            environ['REMOTE_USER'] = user

        return application(environ, start_response)
    return auth_app
```

Then you can write (for Trac)

```
application = use_basic_auth(trac.web.main.dispatch_request)
```

or, in my case (for Mercurial)

```
application = use_basic_auth(hgweb(config))
```

This obviously won’t work if you’re using something other than HTTP Basic authentication. In that case, you could either do what byoungb suggests (albeit using a better header name), or you could move the authentication to the Python end of things rather than getting nginx to do it.  The downside of the latter is that you *might* be more vulnerable if there's some security hole somewhere.

Comment: I have always seen X-* used and never really thought much of it. But makes sense that there would be some sort of convention somewhere.